# How to keep data frame format when applying sapply in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, plyr

I wrote a function that splits my data frame into a sequence of 3 columns each (which represent sample replicates) and applies another function on these replicates. The latter replaces all values by "NA" if not at least two out of three samples in this replicate sequence are above a certain threshold, in this case a value of 16.

This is the example code:

```
# Install and load packages
if (!require(plyr)) install.packages('plyr')
library(plyr)
if (!require(dplyr)) install.packages('dplyr')
library(dplyr)

# Create example data frame
df <- data.frame (ID  = c('data1', 'data2', 'data3'), 
    sample1 = c(2, 18, 3),
    sample2 = c(4, 17, 16),
    sample3 = c(3, 11, 2),
    sample4 = c(22, 11, 35),
    sample5 = c(10, 8, 22),
    sample6 = c(17, 9, 11))

# Function for threshold settings
setThreshold <- function(df) {
    thresholded_replicates <- data.frame(
        sapply(split.default(df[2:ncol(df)], 
            rep(seq_along(df), 
            each = 3, 
            length.out = ncol(df)-1)
            ), function(df) {
                 df <- df %>%
                 mutate(rowsum = apply(df, 1, function(x) sum(x > 16))) %>% 
                 mutate_at(1:ncol(df), funs(ifelse(rowsum < 2, NA, .))) %>%
                 select(-rowsum)
               return(df)
        }
    ))
    return(thresholded_replicates)
}

df_th <- setThreshold(df)
```

The input dataframe looks like this:

```
> df
        ID sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6
1 data1       2       4       3      22      10      17
2 data2      18      17      11      11       8       9
3 data3       3      16       2      35      22      11
```

Below the data frame after applying the function:

```
> df_th
                X1         X2
sample1 NA, 18, NA 22, NA, 35
sample2 NA, 17, NA 10, NA, 22
sample3 NA, 11, NA 17, NA, 11
```

The function works nicely, it replaces all values in the replicate rows by "NA" that do not contain at least two values that are greater than 16. However, the format of the data frame is mixed up, the resulting data frame should look like this:

```
     sample1 sample2 sample3 sample4 sample5 sample6
1      NA      NA      NA      22      10      17
2      18      17      11      NA      NA      NA
3      NA      NA      NA      35      22      11
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is complete base R version, where we use `lapply` and `rowSums` to turn rows to `NA`.

```
do.call(cbind, lapply(split.default(df[2:ncol(df)], rep(seq_along(df), each = 3, 
       length.out = ncol(df)-1)), function(x) {x[rowSums(x > 16) < 2, ] <- NA;x}))

#  1.sample1 1.sample2 1.sample3 2.sample4 2.sample5 2.sample6
#1        NA        NA        NA        22        10        17
#2        18        17        11        NA        NA        NA
#3        NA        NA        NA        35        22        11
```